# vb.net - Why is += operator not allowed for ULong (UInt64)?

Tags: .net, vb.net

How come I can assign an ULong a literal value at creation

```
Dim myULong As ULong = 0
```

but with option strict on, I cannot increment like below?

```
myULong += 1
```

Visual Studio 2013 is telling me

```
Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Decimal' to 'ULong'.
```

I have no idea how VS makes out a decimal in that line of code...

Thanks for your input!

Comment: History, Visual Basic has a lot of it.  You will have to use `1UL` here.

Comment: you should use literals to represent the proper datatype, 1UL, I always do this in every math operation or variable declaration even for integers, numeric literals its a practical custom coding.

Comment: And once again `Option Strict On` saved the day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If two operands are of different data types, the result of an arithmetic expression will be of the data type that is more precise.

Since `UInt64.MaxValue` is greater than `Int32.MaxValue` adding `UInt64`value to an `Int32` value   yields a `Decimal`(see: [Widening and Narrowing Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1e94s7e.aspx)) not an `Int32` which range is too small compared to `UInt64`. The result could also be negative, so `UInt64` is not a good alternative either. Actually there is no implicit conversion from `UInt64` to any other integral type, not even `Int64`(`Long`) since it's range is smaller.

That's why you get the compiler error if you try to reassign the result to the `UInt64` vaue.

You either have to cast it:

```
myULong = CULng(myULong + 1)
```

or (better) use `1UL` in the first place:

```
myULong += 1UL
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ex274z.aspx):

> Type-unsafe conversions,  cause a compiler error with Option Strict
>   On. For example, if you try to add an Integer variable to a Double
>   variable and assign the value to an Integer variable, a compiler error
>   results, because a Double variable cannot be implicitly converted to
>   type Integer.

By the way, C# will automatically use the correct type, so this compiles:

```
UInt64 myULong = 1;
myULong += 1;   // here 1 is treated as UInt64
```

whereas this won't compile

```
myULong += -1;  // -1 is Int32
```

Comment: Why doesn't UInt64 + [U]Int32 -> [U]Int64?

Comment: Will `myULong += 1UL` not work?  (I'm not super familiar with VB, .NET, or VS)

Comment: @user2864740 Because an Int32 could be a negative number.  Consider some positive UInt64 less than Abs(Int32.Min) added to Int32.Min.  The result would be some negative number.

Comment: @user2864740: because `Int32` can be negative, so the result of `UInt64 + Int32` can also be negative. Hence `UInt64` is not an option.